# Why is it not possible for a UserControl to inherit from something else than UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, base-class

I need all my user controls to have some similar functionality. So my user control it is as:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;


namespace WpfApplication26
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ok now I want to make that control inherit from a base class where I have all my functionality as a result I now have something like:

[image]

I posted a picture to show you guys the error that I am getting. UserControl1 should be able to inherit from DraggableControl Since DraggableControl inherits from UserControl. I don't understand why visual studio does not let me compile that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a WPF UserControl inherit a WPF UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887519/how-can-a-wpf-usercontrol-inherit-a-wpf-usercontrol)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably because you didn't change the XAML declaration accordingly.

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887519) may help.

However, it looks like you can't derive from a class that has XAML :-(

Comment: what will I have to change on the xaml? the x:Class attribute?

Comment: But nowhere in the XAML one can specify where it inherits from, I guess it assumes UserControl. Here is a good set of options but as far a I know XAML won't play nice with other base classes, there are some options though, take a look at this article http://gen5.info/q/2009/02/10/subverting-xaml-how-to-inherit-from-silverlight-user-controls/