# Inheritable Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have an assortment of user controls and I'm trying to see if I can create a base class for them with some dependency properties.

Specifically, most of my user controls follow this format...

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding MyDataContext}" >
    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding MyExpandedByDefault}">
        <TextBlock>Some text</TextBlock>
    </Expander>
</UserControl>
```

Of course, normally if this was just a one-off, I'd write the dependency property in the code behind for the above user control. However, since I have multiple user controls that follow the same format, I'd like to put something like the following in a base class...

```
public bool ExpandedByDefault
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ExpandedByDefaultProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ExpandedByDefaultProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedByDefaultProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandedByDefault", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBaseView), new UIPropertyMetadata());
```

I would like for that to be inherited somewhere so in my main window I can do something like....

```
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <my:Alpha ExpandedByDefault="True" />
        <my:Bravo ExpandedByDefault="False" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have made a base class like so...

```
public class ViewBase : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedByDefaultProperty =
                 DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandedByDefault",
                                             typeof(bool),
                                             typeof(FiapaDbViewerBase),
                                             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    public bool ExpandedByDefault
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(ExpandedByDefaultProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            this.SetValue(ExpandedByDefaultProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to inherit it in the code behind for my user control like so....

```
public partial class MyUserControl : ViewBase
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I get an error saying

```
Partial declarations of 'MyUserControl' must not specify different base classes
```

And I cannot find the other part of the partial class in my solution??? I've tried searching for it in the whole solution...

Comment: What is your question? This looks like you already have the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have inheritance. Like so:

1. Define a base class:

   ```
   public class BaseExpanderUC : UserControl
   {
       public bool ExpandedByDefault
       {
           get { return (bool)GetValue(ExpandedByDefaultProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ExpandedByDefaultProperty, value); }
       }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty ExpandedByDefaultProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("ExpandedByDefault", typeof(bool), typeof(MyBaseView), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
   }
   ```
2. Define an inherited classes:

   ```
   public class Alpha : BaseExpanderUC{}
   public class Bravo : BaseExpanderUC{}
   ```
3. In each of the XAMLs of each inherited classes (Alpha and Bravo above), use this makup:

   ```
   <BaseExpanderUC>
       <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding MyExpandedByDefault,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BaseExpanderUC}}}">
           <TextBlock>Some text</TextBlock>
       </Expander>
   </BaseExpanderUC>
   ```

   Where "local" is an xmlns for the namespace of BaseExpanderUC.

This will demand you to define the UI for each UC. If you can have a common UI for all controls, I'd strongly suggest that you use a custom control (probably inheriting Expander). Then you'll have to define the UI only once, in a `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Oops, copy-pasted your code, didn't change the root element in XAML. See my edit in clause 3.

Comment: Thanks for your edit... but how does that fix the partial class error I'm getting? Thanks.

Comment: Derp. Thanks. I missed the part where you Changed the opening tag to

    `<BaseExpanderUC>`.

I also noticed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887519/how-can-a-wpf-usercontrol-inherit-a-wpf-usercontrol) previously answered question too in case anyone needs it.