# Subclassing a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, subclassing

I am trying to subclass a UserControl after reading the following:
[How can a WPF UserControl inherit a WPF UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887519/how-can-a-wpf-usercontrol-inherit-a-wpf-usercontrol)

But I seem to have missed something.

Base class, which is not partial nor does it have an XAML:

```
namespace HTTPFreeForm
{
    public class HTTPBaseForm : UserControl, IForm
    /* ... more content ... */
}
```

Subclass codebehind:

```
namespace HTTPFreeForm
{
    public partial class HTTPFreeForm : HTTPBaseForm
    /* ... more content ... */
}
```

Subclass XAML:

```
<local:HTTPBaseForm x:Class="HTTPFreeForm.HTTPFreeForm" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HTTPFreeForm"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <!-- ... more content ... -->
</local:HTTPBaseForm>
```

When I try to build, I receive the following error:

> Error 2   The type name 'HTTPBaseForm' does not exist in the type 'HTTPFreeForm.HTTPFreeForm' c:\MyProject\HTTPFreeForm\obj\Debug\HTTPFreeForm.g.cs   42  54  HTTPFreeForm

**What am I missing or doing wrong?**

Comment: You have conflict on names your namespace is named the same as class. Change that and try again.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. If you write it as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested comment to answer.

You have conflict on names your namespace is named the same as class. Change that and try again.