# WPF UserControl inheriting another UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I am trying to inherit an usercontrol in WPF the way mentioned in [How can a WPF UserControl inherit a WPF UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887519/how-can-a-wpf-usercontrol-inherit-a-wpf-usercontrol)

```
namespace DMS.Presentation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for WorkSpaceViewControl
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class WorkSpaceViewControl : UserControl
    {
        public WorkSpaceViewControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void InitializeComponent()
        {

        }
    }  

}
```

And code doesn't give any error thus far. But when I inherit it in a new usercontrol:

```
namespace DMS.Presentation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AnimalWorkSpaceView.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AnimalWorkSpaceView : WorkSpaceViewControl
    {
        public AnimalWorkSpaceView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }

}
```

And it's XAML file is:

```
//I have tried both WorkSpaceViewControl:UserControl and UserControl:WorkSpaceViewControl here


<UserControl:WorkSpaceViewControl x:Class="DMS.Presentation.WorkSpaceViewControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DMS.Presentation"
             xmlns:WorkSpaceViewControl="clr-namespace:DMS.Presentation"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

</UserControl:WorkSpaceViewControl>
```

I get a message that partial modifier doesn't exist. Another Partial Declaration of *WorkSpaceViewControl* exists. So how should I implement it and where have things gone wrong? My whole project is stuck due to this inheritance bottle-neck since January. Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the answer you've referenced, your derived `UserControl` XAML should look more like this:

```
<local:WorkSpaceViewControl x:Class="DMS.Presentation.AnimalWorkSpaceView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DMS.Presentation"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
</local:WorkSpaceViewControl>
```

You had declared two different XML namespaces, `local` and `WorkSpaceViewControl`, both referring to `"clr-namespace:DMS.Presentation"`. You need just one of them (so I kept `local`, it being more idiomatic), and you need to use the namespace to qualify the type name `WorkSpaceViewControl`.

Thus, the XAML declaration starts as `<local:WorkSpaceViewControl ...`

In addition, the `x:Class` value for your derived class needs to be the *derived* class, not the base class. So instead of `"DMS.Presentation.WorkSpaceViewControl"`, that should be set to `"DMS.Presentation.AnimalWorkSpaceView"` as shown above.